# Function similar to array_map to re-index an array

Tags: php, arrays, php-5.3

I've recently been using [`array_map`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-map.php) to replace this kind of code:

```
$users = ...;
$usersIds = array();
foreach ($users as $user) {
   $usersIds[] = $user->getId();
}
```

with

```
$users = ...;
$usersIds = array_map(function ($user) {
    return $user->getId();
}, $users);
```

It's more elegant, and i *guess* that this more efficient.

Now i'd like to know if the following code could be improved with a function similar to `array_map`:

```
$users = ...;
$indexedUsers = array();
foreach ($users as $user) {
    $indexedUsers[$user->getId()] = $user;
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As you already have the keys, just combine it:

```
$indexedUsers = array_combine($usersIds, $users);
```

Apart from that, `foreach` normally is elegant, especially these trivial cases you outline don't need much function logic, so I'd prefer the iterator pattern here instead of going functional.

Comment: I generally agree, so +1. There shouldn't be (much) performance gain / loss unless there is some more logic involved.

Answer (score 2):

First off, I doubt `array_map()` is faster than your original `foreach` loop. Never change code because you *think* it's faster. Of course, if you think it's more elegant and the speed difference is insignificant, then nobody should care.

You can often think of using iterators in these contexts:

```
class ArrayGetIdIterator extends ArrayIterator
{
  public function key()
  {
    return $this->current()->getId();
  }
}

$indexedUsers = iterator_to_array(new ArrayGetIdIterator($users));
```

To minimize boilerplate code and maximize reusability, the constructor could accept some type of arguments (e.g, which function to call) and you could create a static helper.

Although, personally, I would just take your original code, wrap it into a reusable function and call it a day.

Answer (score 1):

You can build on your former success and use array_combine...

```
$get_user_id = function($user) {return $user->getId();};
$indexedUsers = array_combine(array_map($get_user_id, $users), $users);
```

Comment: `array_walk` returns a boolean, and array_combine expects the first argument to be an array. Your code does not work.

Comment: My apologies, that's a typo; it was meant to mirror your code and be array_map...

Comment: As evident in the order of parameters :-) Change has been made.